# Can I test a replacement iPhone I bought at auction for carrier compatibility by inserting the SIM without screwing up my existing account?

Tags: iphone, sim, compatibility

I bought a replacement iPhone SE (older model) because battery on my old one was waning. I need to test it before return window expires to make sure it is compatible with my carrier (Verizon) but I don't want to activate it yet.  Is that possible to do by inserting a SIM the carrier sent me?

Answer (score 1):

I believe Verizon in the US keeps their gates shut and you need their help to activate devices. There’s probably no harm in swapping the sim, especially if you have an alternate way to call them / get support if your phone stops working.

- https://www.verizon.com/solutions-and-services/activate-my-device/